# Can I use CKEditor 5 Inline or Balloon Editor on a form submission?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'd like to use the CKEditor 5 Inline or Balloon editor on a form submission, but I'm having difficulty.

I can get the submission to work perfectly w/ Classic Editor but the Inline Editor prevents me from typing in the field.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    InlineEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#ck' ) );
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Comment</label>
    <textarea cols="80" rows="10" name="comment" class="form-control" id="ck">foo
</div>
```

On the page, the editor shows up, but I am unable to type into it on Safari (Mac).

I looks like this was possible in [CKEditor 4](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/savetextarea.html), it is possible in 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, `InlineEditor` and `BalloonEditor` are not meant to replace `<textarea>` element. `ClassicEditor` works in this case because it just replaces the whole element with its own containers, but this is not the case for other editors.

CKEditor 4 was kind of one solution to suit all the needs. There were a lot of things happening under the hood. With CKEditor 5 we give you builds and an API, but the integration needs to be done by the outside developer. I am not saying this will never change, although this is the status for now.

Additionally, at the moment, neither editor will replace `<textarea>` value as you type.

If you want to use `ClassicEditor`, you might want to replace `<textarea>`'s value with editor data on form submission.

```
const textarea = document.querySelector( '#ck' );

ClassicEditor
    .create( textarea )
    .then( editor => { window.editor = editor } );

document.getElementById( 'submit' ).onclick = () => {
    textarea.value = editor.getData();
}
```

If you would like to use `InlineEditor` or `BalloonEditor`, you need to use `<div>` instead of `<textarea>`. You could create a hidden input field and set its value to editor data in a similar fashion as above.